# Resource(resx) Custom helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, resx

I'm a first time poster long time listener and I would really be interested in reading about some of your localization architectures and, eventually, to get feedback on our approach (as follows).

I would like some advice on an approach we're thinking of using with resource files. We are using MVC 3.0 and have a website project and a resource project. In the resource project we have a structure which mimics the same structure as the website e.g. *controller -> view -> file*.

We reference the resx files in the views by importing the resource namespace on the top of the view/control e.g. `<%@ Import Namespace="MyAppResources.Resources.Website.Home" %>` and then reference the resx value we need by using `<%= Index.SomeText %>` where index is the name of the resource file.

What we were thinking of doing and would love some advice is instead of using this approach is to divide the resource resx structure into website areas and use a helper e.g. `LocalizationHelper.GetValue("Home", "SomeText")` where "Home" is the name of the resource file and `"SomeText"` is a value in that resx file. The reason we would do this is not to have to keep compiling the resource project for every small copy change we make (as we may need a quick fix for our deployed environment) and also it will probably  be the most commonly used helper in the website project so this would keep things short and consistent. The Localization helper would also store the values in a cached dictionary so if a value is used more than once it would retrieve it from the cache.

Does anyone know of a better approach or improvements we have not thought of?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a database to store the localized values instead of a RESX file.

Using a database would prevent you from needing to make any code/file deployments to update your application.  Furthermore, you could build a GUI interface for modifying the localized values (which is a great feature for the site administrators/editors).